# UITextView - Paste action inserts empty string on iOS 11

Tags: ios, uitextview, copy-paste

I have a regular `UITextView` that has Paste support out of the box via `UIKit`. Nothing fancy in the textView. Up until iOS 10, including, paste worked as expected.

As of iOS 11 when I paste text into it using the `UIMenuController` action, no text is being paster (The `UIMenuController` disappears after tapping on paste).

Debugging the `UITextViewDelegate`'s method:

`- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView*)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString*)text`,

shows an empty string is about to be inserted, although the PasteBoard has a non empty value, but I can't figure out why.

**However, when copying the url from Safari's address bar, the paste action works.**

--

I know Apple made changes to the Paste functionality in iOS 11, however, according to the [Cut-Copy-Paste Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations.html), `UITextView`'s paste functionality should remain the same.

iOS 11 also introduced a `UITextPasteDelegate`.
I managed to hack a working fix for the Paste action using it but this **doesn't feel like the way to go**:

declare implementation of `UITextPasteDelegate` and do the following in the class/controller holding your UITextView:

```
//declare yourself as a paste delegate
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textView.pasteDelegate = self;
}

//Set a Hook to know there's a paste action while I'm the first responder - fired when Paste was tapped
- (void)textPasteConfigurationSupporting:(id<UITextPasteConfigurationSupporting>)textPasteConfigurationSupporting transformPasteItem:(id<UITextPasteItem>)item API_AVAILABLE(ios(11.0)) {
    [self paste:textPasteConfigurationSupporting];
}

//generic paste action handler
- (void)paste:(id)sender {
    UIPasteboard *gpBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    if ([gpBoard hasStrings]) {
        id<UITextPasteConfigurationSupporting> pasteItem = (id<UITextPasteConfigurationSupporting>)sender;
        if ([pasteItem isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
            UITextView* myTextView = (UITextView*)pasteItem;
                [myTextView insertText:[gpBoard string]];
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, the same goes for pasting text into a `UISearchBar`.

My project uses iOS 9.0 as it's deployment target.
I did not fool around with first-responder chains or messed them up.

--

If I open a new project and use the same UITextView functionality, paste works as expected without the hacky fix.

Comment: please read its latest documentation if you are copied something out from the app and you assume its will be automaticuly srink in app like before it works but now they stop working coz of some security reason. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard

Comment: @NitinGohel, the doc regarding `UIPasteboard` which you've referenced describes non-user phasing access to the pasteboard.
This is not the case while using the `UIMenuController`'s explicit paste action in which the user initiated the paste.
Also, according to the [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations.html) I've referenced in my question, `UIKit` components like `UITextView` support this out of the box.

Comment: I had an instance where `hasStrings` was true, but `string` produced a nil value and caused an app crash, so would make sure to check it before calling insertText with it. Otherwise awesome workaround!